# CUDA Stack push and pop

Tags: stack, cuda

I am trying to implement a stack that I can push (x,y) and pop values.

I have look all over the Nvidia forum however I can see to find anyway of implementing a stack.

If anyone could show the simplest example that would be very useful!

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think stack implementation for CUDA differs from what you have in regular C++. Just keep in mind, that your stack will be placed in card RAM and that's no-so-fast memory

Comment: What is the scope of the stack? Thread level, block level, or grid level?

Comment: The CUDA environment is very different from a traditional host PC. A stack will probably perform very poorly. Don't try to simply port existing algorithms to CUDA. Abstract away the implementation and identify homogenous tasks that can be done with massive parallelization.

Comment: A Stack ? That is serial. Unless you have lots of stacks (one per block at least) the data structure is not optimal for the architecture. What are you trying to solve ?

Answer (score 1):

Think over if your stack is really the data structure that will be fast and massively parallel? If yes, you should be able to implement in CUDA, just like you would in C.